Useful necessary conditions for a number $N$ to be balanced?
Inspired by this question
Let us call a positive integer $N$ "balanced" , iff in the decimal expansion , every digit from $0$ to $9$ occurs equally often.
The linked question askes about a positive integer $N$ , such that $N,N^2,N^3$ are all balanced.
I found many examples where $N$ and $N^2$ are balanced and also many examples where $N$ and $N^3$ are balanced , but none where all three numbers are balanced despite enormous effort to find such a triple. Maybe , there is none , in this case , has anyone an idea how we can prove this ?
Since exhaustive search is very time-consuming , I would like to speed up the search and for this , I have the following question :

Apart from the simple fact , that a balanced number must be divisible by $9$ , is there any other useful necessary condition for $N$ to be balanced that I can use to sieve out many positive integers $N$ that cannot do the job ?

Smallest solution in other bases :
   Decimal               Base representation
2  3274                  110011001010
3  371920                200220011211
4  55512                 31203120
5  7517304               3411023204

Examples for the bases $6-9$ :
6  1266725115            325410152043
7  404824602132          41150634225306
8  174759369868062       4757052612301436
9  149858543258270040    887761054156022343


Is it easy to find binary examples?  Base $3$?

I have not checked other bases yet, but this could be a good start.

Have you tried looking for OEIS sequence of numbers $x$ so that $x$ and $x^2$ are both balanced? And sequence for $x$ and $x^3$ both balanced?

Excellent! $\quad$

You can check if the number of digits in $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ are divisible by 10; i.e. $\lfloor \log_{10} x\rfloor +1$, $\lfloor 2\log_{10} x\rfloor +1$, $\lfloor 3\log_{10 }x\rfloor +1$ are all divisible by 10. And to risk stating the obvious, only search numbers which are of $10n$ length.

@Peter  so, considering how rare balanced numbers are to begin with, these examples aren't so bad.  Feels encouraging for base $10$ though I couldn't really justify that.  Might be a very base specific sort of question.

Do you allow leading zeros?  A $10$ digit number will cube to a number with $28-30$ digits.  Can you add leading zeros to the shorter ones to get $30$ digits? That increases the number of possibilities a bit.  Fundamentally there are rather few balanced numbers.  In this answer I show heuristically that it is unlikely to find a $10$ digit example.  The same approach can be extended for more general lengths of $N$.  I did allow leading zeros there.

@RossMillikan No, leading zeros are not allowed.

I wrote a small python script that showed that there are no 10 digit balanced numbers that have both a balanced square and a balanced cube. It found 534 balanced squares and 74 balanced cubes. And obviously the first digit of a 10n digit candidate must be a 4 or higher (else the cube won't have 30n digits)

@Ronald Thank you , this confirms my result that we must search for a $20$-digit example (or more , if we are very unlucky)

$3$ downvotes ! Does any of the downvoters have any suggestion which context I should give ? Those "blind downvotes" begin to suck.

Given the examples in other bases it strikes me that (except for base 2 and 3) obviously 2b digits are required (where b is the base of the number). So I'm not giving up hope that there exists a 20 digit balanced decimal number N for which N^2 and N^3 are balanced too

Well, I don't have any suggestions on how to reduce the search set, but after a few days (about $3.5$) of searching my script issued the following output:
70012415663838792594   = 70012415663838792594
70012415663838792594^2 = 4901738347086139521062051572659749248836
70012415663838792594^3 = 343182542631572906837869753230914766752451101470088699920584

So far it searched about $110,000,000,000$ permutations of $11223344556677889900$; I had 6 scripts running in parallel, one with permutations starting with $4$, one with $5$, and so on, up to $9$. (The number of the permutations mentioned is the total of all scripts).
A second one was found shortly afterwards:
50012645278843169379   = 50012645278843169379
50012645278843169379^2 = 2501264687787393959407108019325683245641
50012645278843169379^3 = 125094863578807342565383950411146207396071829074175826426939

Number 3:
80012867556337949421   = 80012867556337949421
80012867556337949421^2 = 6402058974588078017662313979963154235241
80012867556337949421^3 = 512247096821580628207479651890850904367387354316129393745461

Given the probability estimate Ross calculated (something in the order of magnitude of $e^{-225}$ to find a single one), it is now just as unlikely that his assumption that the digits of $N^2$ and $N^3$ are independently random, is justified.
By now I've searched about $204*10^9$ permutations out of $6*19!/2^{9} = 1,425,528,520,416,000$, which is about $1/7000$. Thank you Daniel for correcting my calculation, even if that means that an extensive search isn't feasible any longer. I'll stop at about 100 hits or so, which I'll publish below (after the correction, I expect thousands of numbers that qualify).
And, btw, if someone's interested in my script, I'll publish it here. Just drop a comment. But warning, the script isn't super beautiful.
In the meantime I've ported the Python script to C, gaining a performance factor of about 10. That helps somewhat.
List of further results:
04: 46418503872990725631 41: 60023916887149543275  78: 80012954295764816733
05: 46432576288139195007 42: 60024299418613578357  79: 80014456993751823672
06: 46435703785982110296 43: 60024517382317568994  80: 80015834521367946297
07: 46437829160053817925 44: 60024839165253891774  81: 80017734245981932656
08: 46457232319087850619 45: 60024873281549356197  82: 80026346472539179581
09: 46461028773128959305 46: 60027381918735562944  83: 80027143927663548159
10: 50014288394796217356 47: 60034929257483817165  84: 80033179872961562544
11: 50017686592738214349 48: 60037148357519924826  85: 80036154429563978127
12: 50025341988649726731 49: 60038591473649812572  86: 80037149862923576514
13: 50025426911473793886 50: 60045692128337147985  87: 80041572936935264817
14: 50026364823194791578 51: 60047629585298731134  88: 80042753199513726846
15: 50026479127538961348 52: 60049253837857169421  89: 80045639215149762387
16: 50027619315828694734 53: 60058497748331921562  90: 80045961542673321978
17: 50027844339716129658 54: 60063428138995214757  91: 80046331591228467957
18: 50028623587419793146 55: 60064988955234271713  92: 80047155822369741396
19: 50028641875326197943 56: 60065313749245129887  93: 80056789394571262143
20: 50029314723945661878 57: 70014252936168873594  94: 80057431465193892762
21: 50038642371495968217 58: 70016738921985436254  95: 80058627346927391145
22: 50039866723492751481 59: 70021891535398676424  96: 80059516332418746927
23: 50042679347821593186 60: 70023379868195462541  97: 90014734886659351722
24: 50048126231839645797 61: 70028948537649513261  98: 90014763527392851648
25: 50049372673848691521 62: 70041897346315269285  99: 90018647478325563291
26: 50051763182394296748 63: 70042623938461595178 100: 90022414369587631857
27: 50052382674399114687 64: 70046949852583123617 101: 90023467451921583876
28: 50063138724761599284 65: 70051283613944975862 102: 90032755971848342616
29: 50063349198176472582 66: 70051319693826784524 103: 90035811249674386752
30: 50063493812452789617 67: 70051738945236621498 104: 90036142835784725196
31: 50063981736258194472 68: 70053591213246789648 105: 90041387265721853496
32: 50064815972943826731 69: 70054881573436692129 106: 90044526728317168359
33: 50067231994614388572 70: 70056522164994318837 107: 90048793611645327285
34: 50072862967958434131 71: 70061234938289476155 108: 90051826643895277314
35: 50073115692783849462 72: 70061594451793368282 109: 90052184677964521338
36: 60018734739592645182 73: 70062674518459933218 110: 90053411472783596628
37: 60019739587423628514 74: 70066288351219449375 111: 90053825674941763812
38: 60021795163825944783 75: 70066849571839435221 112: 90058258714143396762
39: 60021979853148627543 76: 70068349611539578242
40: 60023827399114684575 77: 80012947631864295375

I don't think publishing more results here makes sense. So far only 18 of 20 digits were permuted which makes it likely that the 112 results found only scratch the surface.
My program can be found at https://pastebin.com/F63iKAcv . Though not as fast as Daniel Mathias' version, it stil calculates 1 billion permutations in 43s on my machine.

@danielmathias You're absolutely right. I'll correct that. Thank you for pointing that out. And yes, I'm aware that if the number starts with 4, it should start with at least 46. Given the number of the rest of the permutations that doesn't reduce the search space significantly though.

@DanielMathias I've added your results to the list. So far I've searched about $1.5 * 10^{12}$ permutations, around 1/1000 of the total. I'm pretty sure there exist thousands more hits.

@DanielMathias my program is about 10 times slower.That's embarrassing. I thought it wasn't that bad. A factor of 2 or 3, would have been acceptable; I didn't optimize it too much. I'm curious about your implementation now.

updated C code, still mostly uncommented, now 25% faster.

Implementing the 'next perm' algorithm provided another significant improvement, reducing my benchmark time from 88 seconds down to 61 seconds. This is probably as fast as I can get it, and certainly sufficient for distributed computing if there is any interest in a complete evaluation. The new code, along with results showing 124 additional hits, can be viewed via the link in my previous comment.

Strike that... I have just doubled the speed with a new method of counting digits. Benchmark time is now under 30 seconds. Linked code has been updated.

@DanielMathias Awesome! I didn't have to to study all of your code, but I had a look at the counting digits part. I love it!
And yes, the next_perm algorithm allows to split up the task in a trivial way. Give me a machine with 6000 cores and I'll return the complete% list of hits within a day or two (even with my program).

There are $9 \cdot 10!/10=3\ 265\ 920$ permutations of the ten digits that do not start with $0$.  If you write or find code that can take a number and output a permutation you can do that many computations for $10$ digits instead of $9 \cdot 10^9$.  The advantage grows with $20$ digits, where there are about $2 \cdot 10^{15}$ permutations instead of $9 \cdot 10^{19}$ numbers.  This gets you the divisibility by $9$ automatically. You need the leading digits of the first permutation to be at least $464$ to have $N^3$ not start with $0$
Heuristically you are unlikely to find one.  Following on this answer we can compute the chance on the (silly) assumption that the digits of $N^2$ and $N^3$ are chosen independently at random.  Let $N$ have $K$ digits and $k=K/10$ so there are $k$ copies of each digit in $N$.  Allowing leading zeros there are $\frac {K!}{k!^{10}}$ permutations of $N$ balanced digits.  There are $\frac {(2K)!}{((2k)!)^{10}}$ permutations of $2K$ balanced digits, so the chance $N^2$ is balanced is $\frac{(2K)!}{((2k)!)^{10}10^{2K}}$.  The expected number of matches with $N, N^2$ balanced is $\frac{9(2K)!K!}{((2k)!)^{10}10^{2K}k!^{10}}$  Asking for $N^3$ to be balanced gets us another factor with the $2$s changed to $3$s, so the expected number of three way matches is $\frac{9^2(2K)!(3K)!K!}{((2k)!)^{10}10^{2K}k!^{10}((3k)!)^{10}10^{3K}k!^{10}}$ where the factor $9$s account for the fact that all the balanced numbers are divisible by $9$ so the squares and cubes of balanced $N$ are $9$ times as likely to be balanced.
For $k=1$ this indicates the expected number is about $0.030$ so it would not be shocking to find an example but calculation has shown there is none.  For $k=2$ the expected number is about $e^{-225}$ and it quickly drops for higher $k$.
